# How to handle multiple related objects (nesting within objects)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Due to the way my database is designed, images are not stored with the project.

This is because there is no set amount of images per product. Some may have 1 image, others may have 10.

I would like my API to return content nested within itself. Currently, my code simply repeats the entire object when additional images exist for the item.

I am using Django Rest Framework:

```
class ProductDetailView(APIView):

    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        filters = {}
        for key, value in request.GET.items():
            key = key.lower()
            if key in productdetailmatch:
                lookup, val = productdetailmatch[key](value.lower())
                filters[lookup] = val

        qset = (
            Product.objects
            .filter(**filters)
            .values('pk', 'brand')
            .annotate(
                image=F('variation__image__image'),
                price=F('variation__price__price'),
                name=F('variation__name'),
            )
        )

        return Response(qset)
```

Currently, an item with 3 images pointing to it will look like this:

```
[{
        "name": "Amplitiue jet black",
        "brand": "Allup",
        "price": "$1248",
        "vari": "917439",
        "image": "url1",
    },
    {
        "name": "Amplitiue jet black",
        "brand": "Allup",
        "price": "$1248",
        "vari": "917439",
        "image": "url",
    },
    {
        "name": "Amplitiue jet black",
        "brand": "Allup",
        "price": "$1248",
        "vari": "917439",
        "image": "url",
    },
```

]

Ideally, it should look like this, combining all the images within an array:

```
{
    "name": "Amplitiue jet black",
    "brand": "Allup",
    "price": "$1248",
    "vari": "917439",
    "images": [
        "url1",
        "url2"
        "url3"
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [ListApiView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview) together with a [ModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer). Don't put the filtering in the `get` method, the Django class based view way is to use `get_queryset` for that.

```
from rest_framework import serializers, generics

class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ("url",)

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ImageSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ("name", "brand", "price", "vari", "images")

class ProductListView(generics.ListAPIView): # it is not a details view 
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        filters = {}
        for key, value in self.request.GET.items():
            key = key.lower()
            if key in productdetailmatch:
                lookup, val = productdetailmatch[key](value.lower())
                filters[lookup] = val
         return Product.objects.prefetch_related("images").filter(**filters)
```

The image list in the JSON will be objects with one "url" element instead of just a list of urls, but this is more consistent with REST standards anyway.

Comment: Do I need to import something at the top? I get the error "name 'ModelSerializer' is not defined". I have already imported from rest_framework import serializers
from django.core import serializers

Comment: I've edited to include imports. BTW it's in the documentation links I provided - you should really take the time to read through the Django REST framework docs before starting to use it.

Comment: Nope- still the same problem with imports. I've read through the django REST docs but still no luck - 'module' object has no attribute 'ModelSerializer'

Comment: There most definitely is a `rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer` class. I can't tell where you go wrong here.

Comment: No it really does keep telling me it has no attribute Model Serializer (http://dpaste.com/37M29W5)

Comment: I suspect you are not importing the real DRF serializers module or it's corrupted. Debug and check `serializers.__path__`.